# Can someone help me with my discord bot code error?

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py, bots

When i run the code it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\DiscordBot.py", line 1, in 
import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

idk how to fix this, please help me.

Comment: How did you install the Python discord module? Did you follow the instructions on https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/?

Answer (score 1):

You can install discord using:

```
pip install discord
```

If you are using anaconda, check your python interpreter from PyCharm. Go to `File->Settings->Project Settings->Project Interpreter->Python Interpreters`
Ensure to select correct version of python.exe

e.g.

- For bare python (For this you need to install discord ) `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib`
  (a path similar to this)
- For anaconda you'll see `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`

Select the correct interpreter and you are good to go

In any case, i suggest you to take the time and learn about virtual environment
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html